# Is there a best way i can select all the topics and questions on each topics and display them onec in php

Tags: php, html, sql

I have two tables **"setTearmlyExam.php"** and **"setTopics.php"**, what i want to do is this:
in the **"setTearmlyExam.php"** i have a form with two select options, a radio button and a start button. each select option has an option from the database.

what am trying to do here is: when the start button is cliked, its will redirect to the **"setTopics.php"** and there display all the topics and question using the selected information on the **"setTearmlyExam.php"**.
I have two table where am selecting the data that will be displayed in the **"setTopics.php"**

The **olevelguestion**:
[image]

Topics:
[image]

"setTearmlyExam.php"

```
<form action="setTopics.php " method="POST" class="col s12" center>
    <!-- setTopics.php -->
    <div>
        <label>Select Term</label>
        <select name="terms" class="browser-default" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Term</option>
<?php
// Selecting terms from database
$select_terms = $db->query("SELECT * FROM term");
if (!$select_terms) {
    die('QUERY FAILED' .mysqli_error($db));
}
// Ends
// Using while loop tp fatch and loop term titles
while ($row = $select_terms->fetch_assoc()) {
    $termId = $row['termId'];
    $terms = $row['terms'];

    echo "<option value='{$termId}'>{$terms}</option>";
}
?>
        </select>
        <label>Select Subject</label>
        <select name="subjects" class="browser-default" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Subject</option>
<?php                                      
// Selecting subjects from database......
$Select_subjects = $db->query("SELECT * 
                                FROM subjects 
                                ORDER BY subj ASC");
if (!$Select_subjects) {
    die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($db));
}
// Ends..
// Using while loop to fetch the subjects title
while ($rw = $Select_subjects->fetch_assoc()) {
    $subjId = $rw['subjId'];
    $subj = $rw['subj'];
    echo "<option value='{$subjId}'>{$subj}</option>";
}
?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="ST">
        <div class="col 6">
            <label>
            <input class="with-gap" name="Examtype" value="O" type="radio" required/>
            <span>Objective</span>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="col 12">
            <label>
                <input class="with-gap" name="Examtype" value="T" type="radio" />
                    <span>Theory</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card-action centerTxt">
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light " type="submit" name="start">Start
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

"setTopics.php"

```
<form action="">
    <div class="card-content black-text">
        <span class="card-title centerTxt">
            <h4>Subject Title</h4>
        </span>
    <div>
    <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
    <label for="">
        <h6 class="" style="font-size: 15px; color:black;">CLICK ON EACH TOPIC TO SELECT QUESTIONS. <span style="color:red; font-size: 13px;">Don't Select more than 50 Questions.</span></h6>
<?php
    $terms = 'terms';
    $subjects = 'subjects';
    //  $Examtype = $_GET['Examtype'];

    if ($Examtype = 'O') {
        $topics = $db->query('SELECT * FROM topics WHERE  ');
    }
?>
        <h5 class='dropdown-trigger ' style="color:#149fd5;" data-target='dropdown1'>Topics Here</h5>
    </label>
    <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
        <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
            <p>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="" />
                    <span>Yellow</span>
                </label>
            </p>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card-action centerTxt">
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light " type="submit" name="start">Next
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: ok. And specifically what problem are you having? Don't just dump a big piece of code on us and expect us to figure it out...explain your exact issue. Please see also [ask] for more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: the problem am having is this: when it redirect to the setTopics.php page i found it hard to select the two informtion i need, tho have used join but i'm confused on how do go about it

Comment: Ok. So, which information from the setTearmlyExam form is it supposed to be using in order to select the correct rows from Topics? Just the examType? And/or the subjects? Or what? It's not clear what your criteria are. Please edit the question with a more specific description of the requirements.

Comment: the subjects and examtype

Comment: And which field in the database does "examType" map to? I don't see anything with that name, in your pictures.

Comment: In the olevelguestion table the Examtype is as type

Comment: Ok. I don't know precisely what results you're expecting, but maybe it's something like `SELECT * FROM topics t INNER JOIN olevelguestion o ON t.subjId = o.subjId WHERE o.type = ? AND t.subjId = ?` (Obviously the ? are placeholders for parameters which come from the form inputs.)

Comment: P.S. Don't you want to restrict it by term as well? That's on the form, but you didn't mention it when I asked.

Comment: i'm redirecting all of them

Comment: If you don't care about the term then why did you ask the user to select it in the form? You are not using that information for anything when the redirect happens.

Comment: SELECT * FROM topics t INNER JOIN olevelguestion o ON t.subjId = o.subjId WHERE o.type = ? AND t.subjId = ?   this works but, am checking if the O value was selected, if so it should bring me all the topics and questions on esch topics under O type

Comment: It'll bring you all the topics and questions under the O type which are also associated with the selected subject. That's what the AND does... If that's not what you wanted, then - again - you need to be **more specific** about the requirements.

Comment: @ADyson yes that's what i'm trying to do

Comment: `It'll bring you all the topics and questions under the O type which are also associated with the selected subject`...if that's what you're trying to do then that should be the right query. Have you tested it?

Comment: @ADyson i'm trying it now